# Need Firefox add-on to download embedded asf media

Tags: firefox, video, browser-addons, media-player, embedded

I am looking for an add-on which would me allow to **download**
embedded asf media
(without having Windows Media Player installed, or under Linux).

*NOTE: The plugin DownloadHelper doesn't help ;)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one:

[**Media Player Connectivity**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/446) is a platform-independent add-on, which allows to open embedded movies with any media player.

Under Linux, to be able to capture the stream, I could use mencoder (that binary from MPlayer).

Answer (score 1):

Not a Firefox addon and not for Linux ... but i'm using **[SDP Downloader](http://sdp.ppona.com/)** to 'grab' .asf and other video content. All you need is the URL (in FF you'll find it in Page Info/Media).

[image]

*SDP Downloader is freeware.*